# Could not run sudo apt-get update

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates

Every time I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get this error:

```
W: GPG error: https://download.01.org Ubuntu Release: The following signatures couldn't
be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366
```

What should I do? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Please don't use any repository out there! You should only install software from trusted sources!

Comment: Do You really need this repo? If not - I would try to remove the repo to solve the problem.